# How do I present the nicer timeline-oriented style of Facebook permissions request dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth, facebook-ui

When I send a user to the authentication URL recommended by the Facebook developer documentation:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&scope=...
```

I see a dialog similar to this:

[image: current permissions dialog]

I would like to present a dialog like the one I see for other apps, which looks like this:

[image]

Can someone please explain how to achieve this much friendlier appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the documentation I needed here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication